# KVM DNS forwarding not working / reply: REFUSED

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, nameserver, forwarding, dnsmasq

I've set up a couple of VMs for development purposes for a project. The setup includes a local CA for the past, current and future project VMs.

On the guest if can do
`dig staging.testing.lan`
and get the desired response.

But on the host I get a REFUSED response.
The query is not forwarded to the guest.
But on the guest the queries are forwarded to the host.

I tried to add the guest as nameserver but then I get all the host queries to the guest and it gets flooded.

What should I do?

The KVM dnsmasq.conf is:

```
strict-order
server=/iso/192.168.120.2
server=/lan/192.168.120.50
server=/testing.lan/192.168.120.50
local=/lan/
domain=lan
expand-hosts
local=/120.168.192.in-addr.arpa/
pid-file=/run/libvirt/network/dot-lan.pid
except-interface=lo
bind-dynamic
interface=virbr0
dhcp-range=192.168.120.100,192.168.120.250,255.255.255.0
dhcp-no-override
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-lease-max=151
dhcp-hostsfile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/virbr0.hostsfile
addn-hosts=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/virbr0.addnhosts
```

And on the VMs DNS:

```
no-hosts
no-poll
log-queries
domain=lan
expand-hosts
#except-interface=lo
interface=eth0
local=/120.168.192.in-addr.arpa/
host-record=staging.testing.lan,192.168.120.50
```